# Is it possible to schedule Firefox to ONLY update when I boot Kubuntu?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, firefox

I'm getting real tired of Firefox just randomly deciding that nothing is going to load until I restart the browser because it updates itself without asking me first.

Instead, I want it to only update on startup. I don't have to restart Chrome in the middle of a browsing session, and I don't want to have to in Firefox either. I'm  Running Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1398196/289138

Answer (score 4):

Open a new tab in Firefox and type `about:config`. Accept the warning and type `update`. The first entry is `app.update.auto`. Click on the double arrow sign on the right side. That will change the value from `true` to `false`. Close the tab. After restaring Firefox it should not auto-update. See picture [image]

Comment: I disabled that, rebooted the whole machine after doing system updates a few days ago, and it STILL auto updated again today.

Comment: When doing the system updates did you update FF? If so, you might have to change the setting again.

Comment: Obviously, I checked that. The setting is still off.